# Is a level automatically created in MDX? Or do I have a setting in BIDS on

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've noticed that every attribute that isn't a multi-level-hierarchy has an implicit level with the same name as the attribute. For example:

```
[Team].[Name].[All],
[Team].[Name].[Name].[Detroit Lions]
```

I did not create the "Name" level --> it seems to have been automatically created. Is this a convention/standard in MDX that there is **always** a level that is there, or is there a setting I have in BIDS that added in this dimension for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that attributes in dimensions in SSAS are called Attribute hierarchies, which has two levels by default: the All level, which can be removed and the detail level consisting of a leaf level is nothing but the Dimension Members.

> An Attribute Hierarchy is a Hierarchy created by SQL Server Analysis
> Services for every Attribute in a Dimension by default. An Attribute
> by default contains only two levels - An "All" level and a "Detail"
> level which is nothing but the Dimension Members.

therefore the "Name" level is created automatically and can not be removed from the attribute hierarchy.